# How to change styling of input clear button?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm working with a React Native form input field and would like to change the color and positioning of the clear button. The default clear button is too close in color to my background color.

```
<FloatingLabel
    clearButtonMode={'always'}
    style={styles.floatStyle}
    inputStyle={styles.floatInput}
    value={this.state.formData.email}
    keyboardType={'email-address'}
    autoCapitalize={'none'}
    onChangeText={(value) => {
        this.setState({
            formData: {
                ...this.state.formData,
                email: value
            }
        })
}}>Email</FloatingLabel>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the FloatingLabel component?

Comment: @Andrew Here it is: https://github.com/mayank-patel/react-native-floating-labels It is essentially identical to the React Native TextInput component aside from the placeholder label.

Comment: could you share a image of what you are trying to achieve?